# Four table sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following query (its the joins that seem not to be working even though I've tried various bracket options).

```
SELECT
IF(transtable.TRANS_CODE='DEP' OR 
  transtable.TRANS_CODE='XDEP','IN',transtable.TRANS_CODE)
  AS TCODE,
latepmts.ACCTNBR,
latepmts.date,
latepmts.NUMBERPMTSDUE
FROM
latepmts
INNER JOIN savingstable ON savingstable.ACCTNBR = transtable.ACCTNBR
INNER JOIN `loantable` ON latepmts.ACCTNBR = `loantable`.ACCTNBR
      AND `loantable`.MEMBERAGREENBR = savingstable.MEMBERAGREENBR
INNER JOIN transtable ON transtable.ACCTNBR = savingstable.ACCTNBR
GROUP BY latepmts.ACCTNBR,TCODE
```

I keep getting the error : `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column transtable.ACCTNBR' in 'on clause'`

Can anyone help?

Comment: The database is telling you there is no column named "ACCTNBR" in the table named "transtable".  You are trying to reference this column in your first INNER JOIN, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think it's related to this error but you don't have any functions like sum, count etc. in your select clause, so why do you need the group by for? I am not sure if Group by will work in this case...If you want it sorted on latepmts.ACCTNBR,TCODE, shouldn't it be ORDER BY latepmts.ACCTNBR,TCODE?

Comment: but that column does exist!

Answer (score 1):

It is the first occurrence of it when you join your savingstable. You need to join it using latepmnts, like this:

```
SELECT
IF(transtable.TRANS_CODE='DEP' OR 
  transtable.TRANS_CODE='XDEP','IN',transtable.TRANS_CODE)
  AS TCODE,
latepmts.ACCTNBR,
latepmts.date,
latepmts.NUMBERPMTSDUE
FROM
transtable 
INNER JOIN savingstable ON savingstable.ACCTNBR = transtable.ACCTNBR
INNER JOIN `loantable` ON `loantable`.MEMBERAGREENBR = savingstable.MEMBERAGREENBR
INNER JOIN latepmts ON transtable.ACCTNBR = savingstable.ACCTNBR  
   AND latepmts.ACCTNBR = `loantable`.ACCTNBR
GROUP BY latepmts.ACCTNBR,TCODE
```

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't work.  The 'ACCTNBR' in the latepmts table are not the same (loan accounts) as the savingstable.  It is for that reason that I need to create the join as the `loantable`.MEMBERAGREENBR = savingstable.MEMBERAGREENBR creates the link.

Comment: OK, I have re-arranged the tables as per your design. Please try now the updated solution

Answer (score 0):

Your joining the tables in the wrong order.

Savings table should be joined **after** the transtable.  You may have to start with a different table in the from clause to achieve this.

```
   SELECT
   IF(transtable.TRANS_CODE='DEP' OR 
     transtable.TRANS_CODE='XDEP','IN',transtable.TRANS_CODE)
     AS TCODE,
   latepmts.ACCTNBR,
   latepmts.date,
   latepmts.NUMBERPMTSDUE
   FROM
   latepmts
   INNER JOIN savingstable ON savingstable.ACCTNBR = transtable.ACCTNBR <--doesn't exist yet
   INNER JOIN `loantable` ON latepmts.ACCTNBR = `loantable`.ACCTNBR
         AND `loantable`.MEMBERAGREENBR = savingstable.MEMBERAGREENBR
   INNER JOIN transtable ON transtable.ACCTNBR = savingstable.ACCTNBR
   GROUP BY latepmts.ACCTNBR,TCODE
```

Comment: Hi Ben,Still no luck.  Same error.  I've tried rearranging the joins as well but I'm getting the same error. Let me try to explain the tables a bit better:

Comment: ...Savingstable have saving accounts of customers and the customer id (memberAgreenbr).  Loantable have the loan account numbers and their id (memberagreenbr).  latepmts have only loan account numbers (for late paying custommers) and transatable have transactions for both loans and savings.  I want to get the savings account transactions of loan customers.  To do this I need to first get the memberagreenbr(customerid) by linking the loantable and savingstable to get the savings account numbers, then pull those savings account transactions from the transtable.

Comment: ....Hope this helps as I really can't figure this one out.  I know its related to the AND clause in the joins and brackets but every combination I've tried still does't work.